# How can I retrieve the points of the homography computed findHomography and RANSAC?

Tags: c++, opencv, ransac

I am new to OpenCV. I noticed that the line

```
Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );
```

helps to find the homography `H` using RANSAC.

However, I need the locations of the 'purified' matching points after RANSAC and I simply cannot find which function I can use. I need a function that uses RANSAC and returns the matching points' locations after RANSAC.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Try posting also a code snippet

Comment: Sorry. What I mean is that using RANSAC after BFMatcher or FlannBasedMatcher actually further 'purify' the matching points and the findHomography function uses the 'purified' matching points to calculate H.  However, I need the locations of the 'purified' matching points and I simply cannot find which function I can use. I need a function that uses RANSAC and returns the matching points locations after RANSAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[findHomography](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?#findhomography) can optionally provide the mask of inliers and outliers (inliers are what you call *purified* matching).

> C++: Mat findHomography(InputArray srcPoints, InputArray dstPoints, int method=0, double ransacReprojThreshold=3, OutputArray mask=noArray() )
>
> Python: cv2.findHomography(srcPoints, dstPoints[, method[, ransacReprojThreshold[, mask]]]) → retval, mask

You can use only inliers (i.e. points with corresponding `mask` value equals to 1) when doing your match.

Comment: is it possible that that function regularly generates a mask of in and outliers which contains errors? ie some pts are considered as inliers while they shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

when you get truly result of H33 from finghomography, why not perspectiveTransform the match points from mask to frame, then you get many 'purified' matching points.